# Analysis on most popular product combination

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, analytics, logistic-regression

I would need your help with the following

Our goal is to increase our overall share in the market - To do this, we would like to know whether introducing a specific combination of products to different countries would have an impact on our market share.

Following is a mockup data over a period of August and September of 2021 and 2022

| Year | Country | Product | Aug_Sales_Euros | Sept_Sales_Euros |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | Kenya | 20MB_Internet | 12000 | 8000 |
| 2022 | Kenya | 200min_Call | 7000 | 9000 |
| 2022 | Kenya | 10MB_100min | 6000 | 5000 |
| 2021 | USA | 10MB_100min | 9000 | 10000 |
| 2022 | USA | 20MB_Internet | 60000 | 50000 |
| 2022 | USA | 900MB_Internet | 12000 | 8000 |
| 2022 | USA | 400min_Call | 70000 | 8000 |
| 2022 | USA | 200min_Call | 12000 | 8000 |
| 2021 | USA | 400min_Call | 50000 | 8000 |
| 2021 | USA | 200min_Call | 12000 | 8000 |
| 2022 | FRANCE | 200min_Call | 12000 | 8000 |
| 2021 | FRANCE | 200min_Call | 12000 | 8000 |

We would like to know, for instance, which product should be introduced with 200min_call in France such that our overall market share is increased? or which existing product combination has the best results? FYI: we use python for our analysis.

There is a lot more data, with lot more combination of products and countries

How should I approach this problem, or even better, is there an example that I can refer to?

Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your question should be a technical question, you are asking about analytical work as I long as I understood, from a python/pandas point of view that is how you analyse a dataset with the kinda data you have, the code below will allow you to answer a lot of the analytical question you have asked above.

```
#your data
dfS = pd.read_csv('salesData.csv')

#groupby year, country, product, apply sum to the other columns
dfS = dfS.groupby(['Year','Country','Product']).agg({'Aug_Sales_Euros':'sum','Sept_Sales_Euros':'sum'})

#then you can filter by year in this case I did 2021 and by country
#so you can see the best sales for a specific country per year, you can change for any country you have in your data set
#using this very same filter
dfS[(dfS.index.get_level_values(0) == 2021) & (dfS.index.get_level_values(1) == 'FRANCE')]

#here you can select the year and check the most sold products. 3 largest product sold in the month of August
dfS[dfS.index.get_level_values(0) == 2022].nlargest(3, 'Aug_Sales_Euros')

#here you can select the country and check the most sold products. 3 largest product sold in the month of September
dfS[dfS.index.get_level_values(1) == 'USA'].nlargest(3, 'Sept_Sales_Euros')

#you can also filter country, product as you please
dfS[(dfS.index.get_level_values(0) == 2021) & (dfS.index.get_level_values(1) == 'FRANCE') & (dfS.index.get_level_values(2) == '200min_Call')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very subjective question. One thing you can try is cluster the regions based on few relevant variables and observe the regions which have introduced new product along with 200min and change in sales

Answer (score 0):

### Broad recommendation

Many approaches can be taken to do the analysis.

I will recommend some materials and libraries to help:

1. Towards data science has very comprehensive material for data analysis and data science in general. [Example](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-beginners-guide-to-data-analysis-in-python-188706df5447).
2. Online courses are another alternative to learning how to approach data analysis. [Example](https://www.coursera.org/learn/data-analysis-with-python).
3. If you are interested in new techniques and state-of-the-art, I recommend looking directly into the conference proceedings such as [this](https://papers.nips.cc/). Keep in mind that this has a more
4. These are a few of the important libraries in data analysis (considering you are using Python): [Numpy](https://numpy.org/), [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/), [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/), [Scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/), and [Beutiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

These are just a few recommendations. The question is very open, with many possible suggestions. You should first have a basic understanding of the tools and methods.

### Directly answer:

To give you a direct answer to the question, I would first group by country and by-product the value.

To do that, you just have to:

```
In [11]: df.groupby(['col5', 'col2']).size()
Out[11]:
col5  col2
1     A       1
      D       3
2     B       2
3     A       3
      C       1
4     B       1
5     B       2
6     B       1
dtype: int64
```

with the **result** as follow:

```
In [12]: df.groupby(['col5', 'col2']).size().groupby(level=1).max()
Out[12]:
col2
A       3
B       2
C       1
D       3
dtype: int64
```

This would give a first understanding of which product in which country has the most relevance in terms of value. From that result, a deeper analysis needs to be done to understand if it is possible to enter a specific market.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple python3 script that extracts the data from your csv

you could call

```py
mysheets = [('hello.csv', '<number_of_columns>'),('mom.csv', '<number_of_columns>')]

sheets = Sheets(mysheets)
```

```py
import csv

# This is a mock script i drew up to extract csv excel data to file in class form. 

#Sheets class 


class CSV:
    
    def __init__(self, filename, number_of_columns):
        
        self.data = {}
        
        with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
            self.document = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
            for row in self.document:
                try:
                    test = row[number_of_columns-1]
                except:
                    raise Exception('csv incorrectly formatted')
                
                year = row[0]
                self.data[year] = {}
                self.data[year]['Country'] = row[1]
                self.data[year]['Product'] = row[2]
                self.data[year]['Jan_Sales_Euros'] = row[3]
                self.data[year]['Feb_Sales_Euros'] = row[4]
                self.data[year]['Mar_Sales_Euros'] = row[5]
                self.data[year]['Apr_Sales_Euros'] = row[6]
                self.data[year]['May_Sales_Euros'] = row[7]
                self.data[year]['Jun_Sales_Euros'] = row[8]
                self.data[year]['Jul_Sales_Euros'] = row[9]
                self.data[year]['Aug_Sales_Euros'] = row[10]
                self.data[year]['Sep_Sales_Euros'] = row[11]
                self.data[year]['Oct_Sales_Euros'] = row[12]
                self.data[year]['Nov_Sales_Euros'] = row[13]
                self.data[year]['Dec_Sales_Euros'] = row[14]

class Sheets:
    
    def __init__(self, sheet_filenames: list):
        
        self.statistics = ['sales', 'product', 'august_sales', 'sept_sales']
        
        self.information = {}
        self.sheets = set(x[0] for x in sheet_filenames)
        self.columns = set(x[1] for x in sheet_filenames)


        for x in self.sheets:
            self.information[x] = CSV(x)
        
    def compareSheet(self, sheet1, sheet2, to_compare):
        
        sheet1_data = self.information[sheet1].data[to_compare]
        
        sheet2_data = self.information[sheet1].data[to_compare]
        
        if sheet1_data>sheet2_data:
            
            print("this is the what you would see")
        
        
             
sheets = Sheets([('hello.csv',15), ('world.csv',15), ('hi.csv',15), ('mom.csv',15)])
```